# MongoDB $dateToString format expression %G strange behaviour

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a document that has the following property amongst others

```
{
 dueDate: ISODate("2019-12-29T13:00:00.000Z")
}
```

I'm building an aggregation, and in the $project stage, I am attempting the following:

```
 "utcDueDate": "$dueDate",
 "rawDueDate" : {
        "$dateToString" : {
            "date" : "$dueDate", 
            "timezone" : "Australia/Sydney"
        }
    }, 
    "prettyDueDate" : {
        "$dateToString" : {
            "date" : "$dueDate", 
            "format" : "%d/%m/%G", 
            "timezone" : "Australia/Sydney"
        }
    }
```

I am expecting the following output:

- utcDueDate: 2019-12-29T13:00:00.000Z
- rawDueDate: 2019-12-30T00:00:00.000Z
- prettyDueDate: 30/12/2019

However, I am getting **30/12/2020** for prettyDueDate.

If I use %Y instead of %G it works as expected.

%G is meant to be the ISO standard format for year (0000-9999). I am using mongo version 4.0.13

Can anyone please explain why this is happening? Quite a few aggregations that are used for reporting have this format string and I'd really like to avoid having to change them all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior for `%G` since it is using a 'week numbered year' calendar.

There is a very detailed explanation of this behavior [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-40727?focusedCommentId=2232521&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2232521). I've copied a small piece of the explanation below:

> The phrase "ISO 8601 format" in the documentation refers to a way of
>   specifying dates that breaks them up by week number and day number
>   instead of the traditional month and day. Years in this format always
>   begin on Monday, so on years where December 31 is not a Sunday, it
>   gets treated as being part of the next year by the ISO 8601 calendar.